# Get the items from a list that match all itens from another list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two lists:

```
public class KeywordAdCategory
{
    [Key]
    [Column("Ad_Id", Order = 1)]
    public int Ad_Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Category_Id", Order = 2)]
    public int Category_Id { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("Keyword_Id", Order = 0)]
    public int Keyword_Id { get; set; }
}


public IList<int> KeywordIds { get; set;}
```

Values:

```
KeywordIds = { 3510, 5686 }

KeywordAdCategory = 

     5291 | 1 | 3510
     5308 | 5 | 3510
     5310 | 5 | 3510
     5312 | 5 | 3510
     5308 | 5 | 5686
```

I need to extract from KeywordAdCategory only the Ad_Id that match the Keyword_ID 3510 and 5686, so then I should get only 5308.

So far I have:

```
var matchingKac = from kac in keywordAdCategoryQuery
                  where keywordIds.Distinct().Contains(kac.Keyword_Id)
                  select kac.Ad_Id;
```

But it's returning all the records from KeywordAdCategory.

Any ideia?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this by grouping the KeywordAdCategory objects into an anonymous type.

```
var grouped = kacList.GroupBy(x => x.Ad_Id,
                              y => y.Keyword_Id,
                              (id, keywords) => new
                              { 
                                  Ad_ID = id, 
                                  Keywords = keywords.ToList()
                              });
```

Then I can check each unique Ad_ID to see if it matches every keyword in the `keywordIds` array.

```
var resultsList = grouped.Where(x => keywordIds.All(y => x.Keywords.Contains(y)))
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but how do you build kacList from KeywordAdCategory? If I use KeywordAdCategory in the place of kacList, I get the error "Error 1 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<int>' because it is not a delegate type', any ideia why? Thanks

Comment: In your question you use a variable named `keywordAdCategoryQuery` which I do not know the type of, but I assumed it was an `IEnumerable<KeywordAdCategory>`.  In my test I simply used a `List<KeywordAdCategory>` which I had mocked with some data.

Comment: Are you sure you copied my code exactly?  There is an overload of the `GroupBy` method which takes an `IEqualityComparer` but it shouldn't have tried to match that one.  Does it work if you replace `keywordAdCategoryQuery` with `keywordAdCategoryQuery.ToList()`?

Comment: I have done some tests and it works better without the third part of the first GroupBy, can you verify please? tahnks